# Access buttons individually made by a for loop (old Unity GUI, Unity Editor script)

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I've got a problem and I am struggling with this for a couple of days now.

I am making an Editor script and I want to access buttons individually when 
created by a for loop. There is a public class ButtonNode which stores some variables
of the button like name and size.

```
public class ButtonNode
{
    public bool button;         
    public string name = "O";
    public float sizeW = 25f;

    public void AlterButton()
    {
        name = "P";
    }
}
```

Then there is my Editor script in which I create the buttons. This is where I get stuck,
how do I access these buttons individually? For example, I want to change the name of the button
when that button is clicked. How do I do that? Because they are booleans (I don't
really know why, this is the legacy GUI) I can't access the transform.name components etc).

```
public static ButtonNode[] bn = new ButtonNode[10];

void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

    for (int i = 0; i < bn.length; i++)
    {
        bn[i] = new ButtonNode();
        if (bn[i].button = GUILayout.Button(bn[i].name + i, GUILayout.Width(bn[i].sizeW)))
        {
            bn[i].AlterButton();
        }
    }

    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}
```

Comment: You are recreating your `ButtonNode` objects each time, the OnGUI function is being called. You will certainly want to create them inside `OnEnable` or at another point, to avoid overwriting the current buttons.

Comment: If I am running this at startup for example, I still can't access individual buttons. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: In which way do you want to access them? If you want each button to execute different tasks, you probably have to look for another approach. If you just want to change the `name` of each button from 'O' to 'P', then this should work.

Comment: I think we are on the right track, I noticed that my startup wasnt really one frame, but still ran multiple times so they are still being recreated everytime. I can't think of a good way to only run this once, though. They are visible when I create them every frame, but when I am creating the buttons once with a boolean they are not visible.

Comment: You can remove the initialization and set `bn = null`. You then check in OnGUI if `bn == null` and create the array and all buttons. The code should then look similar to [this](http://pastebin.com/Qb4xkEek)

Comment: I am glad it helped. I will post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are recreating your `ButtonNode` objects each time, the `OnGUI` function is being called. You will certainly want to create them at a single point in your application.

You can remove the initialization and set `bn = null`. You then check in `OnGUI` if `bn == null` and create the array and all buttons. The code should then look similar to this:

```
public static ButtonNode[] bn = null;

void OnGUI()
{
    GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

    if (bn == null)
    {
        bn = new ButtonNode[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < bn.Length; ++i)
        {
            bn[i] = new ButtonNode();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bn.length; i++)
    {
        // this line has to be removed, to avoid recreation of buttons
        // bn[i] = new ButtonNode();
        if (bn[i].button = GUILayout.Button(bn[i].name + i, GUILayout.Width(bn[i].sizeW)))
        {
            bn[i].AlterButton();
        }
    }

    GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
}
```